# Relationships Inside Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, model

I'm trying to find out how to work with the following relationship. I have a users table with a few fields like id, username, name, role_id. I have a roles table that has an id, and name field.

All users have one role and roles belong to all users so that more than one user can have the same role obviously. I have the following in the corresponding models.

I'm trying to figure out what I need to do so that when I do a call for all users it will get the name of the role and show it instead of the role_id.

```
class Role extends Eloquent {

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('User'); // this will get all the users that have a role_id that matches it's own id
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Role'); // this will select the role by 'role_id' and return an instance
    }
}
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use eager loading, To get the name of the role you just call the function you defined in user model.

```
$user->role->name;
```

see [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) for more Information.

Comment: Are my relationships correct or do I need to do the belongsToMany relationship for either of the models.

Comment: If the user has more than one role then you need to create pivot table and use Many to Many relation. In Laravel docs there is an example for this type of behaviour. http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships see Many to Many relations.

Comment: A user can only have one role at at time. They can only be a basic user, moderator, or admin at a time.